# Is it considered bad practice to use InternalsVisibleTo for Unit Test Code?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Sample code in framework's `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo
                          ("Test.Company.Department.Core")]
```

Is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No, it is not considered bad practice. There is no other way, if the classes you want to test are internal to your assembly for good reasons. Just not testing them would be a lot worse.

Comment: if your classes are internal only then there is no way to use them. You probably expose a public API which uses the internal classes. Then it should be possible to test the internal classes through the public API (however it can be more or less difficult). Testing through the public API is preferable since it makes refactoring interal APIs easier.

Comment: @Rickard: I strongly disagree: The public API is meant to be easily usable by others. Testing all functionality of the internal types through the public API is at least cumbersome. Behind every not-so-small API interface might be a whole graph of objects with complex interactions and branches. Testing the public API is more like an integration test.

Comment: so you feel ok testing private members and methods as well?

Comment: No. The difference is in the size. You can't compare a private method to an internal class or even a complete object graph.

Comment: ok, I aggree. My point, which may have been too general, is that InternalsVisibleTo shouldn't be your first choice, rather use it when it makes sense, e.g. the size of the API is significant.

Comment: I can agree with that. My rational behind saying that it is OK is simple pragmatism: If you can't write reasonable focused tests with a reasonable amount of effort when just using the public API, use `InternalsVisibleTo`. Otherwise, use the public API.

Answer (score 33):

Personally I think it's fine. I've never gone along with the dogma of "only test public methods". I think it's good to *also* have black box testing, but white box testing can let you test more scenarios with simpler tests, particularly if your API is reasonably "chunky" and the public methods actually do quite a lot of work.

Likewise, in a well-encapsulated project you may well have several internal types with *only* internal methods. Now presumably those will have a public impact so you *could* do all the testing just through the public types - but then you may well need to go through a lot of hoops to actually test something that's *really* simple to test using `InternalsVisibleTo`.

Answer (score 4):

`InternalsVisibleTo` could be useful if you need to test sub parts of your API which you don't want to expose.

However, testing through the public API is preferable since it makes refactoring internal APIs easier. Use `InternalsVisibleTo` with care and only when appropriate, e.g. the size of the API is significant.

Comment: _"...it makes refactoring internal APIs easier"_: a concrete point to consider, thankies.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's perfectly reasonable to do that.

I find it very useful for dependency injection. If I have a class with a constructor that takes in a few dependencies to allow it to be unit tested I often mark it internal and expose it in my unit test project. Then I'd have a public (parameterless, or at least with far fewer parameters) constructor. This keeps the public interface clean and still allows for testable code.

Comment: Sounds like bad idea to have test code use different constructor than production code

Answer (score 1):

No, when used correctly, because in some scenarios it's necessary. For instance, you have unit test `A` that needs to test a public member of assembly `B` that uses some internal type also defined in assembly `B`. The unit test needs this type, thus you must use `InternalsVisibleTo`.

It is also useful for protecting code. A for instance is an Activation assembly. You may only want one module in your solution to access your activation assembly, and prevent anyone from adding a reference to it and calling methods. You can make the types and members internal, expose them only to a signed assembly with a public key token, and its hidden from the rest of the world.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is bad practice because if you have used the SOLID principles then you really shouldn't have to use "InternalsVisibleTo". However i know in the "real world" you get all sorts of code.....so the pragmatic approach is best.

Also "InternalsVisibleTo" is not ideal in scenarios where you use obfuscation. Obfuscators tend to obfuscate the "internal" stuff. Therefore any external dll that attempts to reference the internals of an obfuscated dll will fail. You can obviously configure the obfuscator to ignore externally referenced items, but that would reduce the effectiveness of any obfuscator.

In my opinion, avoid "InternalsVisibleTo" if you can. But if you have to use it, then there's something wrong with how the code is structured (which you tend to get a lot of).