# Protection Levels and Visual Studio unit tests with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, access-levels

I am setting up some unit tests for a C# project I'm working on, and I opted to use Visual Studio's built-in unit test project. The problem is that I have been giving most of my classes in the project the default, `internal` access level. Now they can't be reached by my unit test project because it is a different assembly.

It would be trivial to just make all my classes in the project `public` so that the unit test project can access them, but isn't it idiomatic to keep classes which are only used internally by a project `internal`?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580710/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-internalsvisibleto-for-unit-test-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make your internals visible to the test project - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 0):

There is built-in support for that, it's called private accessors. Read about here for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385974%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

By the way, please consider whether you really want to unit test the internals of a project. According to some schools, you shouldn't do that, but I understand that it can be useful.

Comment: That article seems seriously outdated - it was last updated for VS 2005, the menu entry it mentions doesn't seem to exist in VS2012, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx seems like a more straightforward approach.

Comment: I already updated my link to VS2010. But you never mentioned your VS version. You're right, it seems they are in fact deprecated. The other solution will work fine.